# Compser projects self-contained?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, composer-php

I'm new to the whole Composer/dependencies game.

I want to know whether if I create a project using, for example `composer require intervention/image` from a cmd window opened in the project root folder, the project is then completely portable. Meaning if I copy the project folder on to another machine with no internet, no composer installed and none of the other dependencies installed, will it still work?

Put another way, when I run `composer require intervention/image` are all of the necessary files cloned locally?

Comment: yeah. composer download the dependencies and create the autoloader, just that.

Comment: Yes, composer will pull in the repo for `intervention/image` and then any dependencies it may have an so on and so fourth. If you're just going to do a copy and paste of all the files from one machine to another then that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You get a local copy of the files so if you manually copy the project, the vendor directory will go with it. If using Git, typically a .gitignore is set to ignore this dir and you won't get it on clone.